# What is legitimate way to get annotations of a pure Kotlin property via reflection, are they always missing?

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to get annotations from Kotlin data class

```
package some.meaningless.package.name

import kotlin.reflect.full.memberProperties

annotation class MyAnnotation()

@MyAnnotation
data class TestDto(@MyAnnotation val answer: Int = 42)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    TestDto::class.memberProperties.forEach { p -> println(p.annotations) }
    println(TestDto::class.annotations)
}
```

I need to process class annotation to make a custom name serialization of GSON however no matter how I declare annotation class it never gets detected

The program always outputs

```
[] 
[@some.meaningless.package.name.MyAnnotation()]
```

which means only class level annotations are present

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, 
it seems that the culprit was, that Kotlin annotations have default **@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)** which is not stressed enough in documentation.

After I added *@Target* to the annotation class it now works properly

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY)
annotation class MyAnnotation()
```

Now it prints out

```
[@some.meaningless.package.name.MyAnnotation()]
[@some.meaningless.package.name.MyAnnotation()]
```

As a side affect it will force the compiler to check that the annotation is applied as required, in current version of Kotlin, if explicit `@Target`is not present only class level annotations are kept but no validity checks performed.

Comment: first, upvote! yeah. but be-careful. you can't get the `property` annotation in Java. which means you can't use the 3rd Java library to resolve the annotation correctly.

Comment: the **culprit** is Kotlin annotation target is applicable anywhere by default. you can see here as further: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.annotation/-target/index.html

Comment: @holi-java I still don't get why the code in my question even compile? If I specify `@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)` than it won't. IMO this is a design issue if it's applicable but not processed. This is very counterintuitive even if it's documented.

Comment: sir, are you sure? maybe your editor is lower version. but you can't compile it.

Comment: The in the question will compile, but if you limit the scope of @Target in the answer it wont.

Comment: this is because `allowedTargets` in annotated `@Target` is empty by default. so you can't annotated it anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

As Kotlin reference said as below:

> If you don't specify a *use-site target*, the target is chosen according to the `@Target` annotation of the annotation being used. If there are multiple applicable targets, the first applicable target from the following: `param`  > `property` > `field`.

To make the annotation annotated on a `property`, you should use [site target](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets), for example:

```
@MyAnnotation
data class TestDto(@property:MyAnnotation val answer: Int = 42)
```

However, annotations with `property` target in Kotlin are not visible to Java, so you should *double* the annotation, for example:

```
@MyAnnotation      // v--- used for property  v--- used for params in Java
data class TestDto(@property:MyAnnotation @MyAnnotation val answer: Int = 42)
```